# Get source repo name from Pull Request in GIT CLI

Tags: git, request, command-line-interface, pull

Is there a way that we can get source repo name from Pull request in GIT CLI. We have forked repo from where developers create Pull Request into Central repo. We want to get the name of forked repo when they raise a Pull Request in CLI.

Comment: What does name of forked repo mean? Could you give an example?

Comment: for example in this repo url: https://vsts.visualstudio.com/VSProject/_git/my-repo, my-repo is repo name